# Mule ESB + TOMCAT Web Application Integration

Tags: java, tomcat, mule, esb

I have a Spring MVC Web application that performs CRUD operations on Tomcat Server. Can I use Mule ESB as a request handler before Tomcat. For example, users request to localhost:8181/user/create (Mule ESB Port) and Mule redirect request to localhost:8080/user/create (Tomcat Server Port) and sends response back over mule. I am using Mule ESB for webservices, but I don't understand how can I use Mule ESB for web application requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new HTTP module released in 3.6 and create a proxy using this flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">

    <http:listener-config name="proxyConfig" host="localhost" port="${proxyPort}" />
    <http:request-config name="requestConfig" host="localhost" port="${httpPort}" />
    <flow name="proxyTemplate">
        <http:listener config-ref="proxyConfig" path="/*" responseStreamingMode="AUTO" parseRequest="false" >
            <http:response-builder statusCode="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]" reasonPhrase="#[message.inboundProperties['http.reason']]" />
        </http:listener>

        <copy-properties propertyName="*" />
        <remove-property propertyName="http.*" />
        <copy-attachments attachmentName="*" />

        <set-property propertyName="X-Forwarded-For" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.remote.address']]" />

        <http:request config-ref="requestConfig" method="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method']]" path="#[message.inboundProperties['http.request.path']]" parseResponse="false" >
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-params expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']]" />
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>

        <copy-properties propertyName="*" />
        <remove-property propertyName="http.*" />
        <copy-attachments attachmentName="*" />
    </flow>

</mule>
```